# MacPorts migrate is not working with Catalina

Tags: macos, macports, macos-catalina

I just updated my computer from High Sierra to Catalina and MacPorts give error.

```
Error: Current platform "darwin 19" does not match expected platform "darwin 17"
Error: If you upgraded your OS, please follow the migration instructions: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: Failed to initialize MacPorts, OS platform mismatch
```

However when I try to migrate it command like these `sudo port -qv installed > myports.txt` are not working also.

I had some version specific packages to run my project. Also I could not find the support for Catalina in their website. What do I need to do?

Comment: Did you reinstall macports from source? Until binary installer is available, that's the only option. https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.source

Comment: @Mihir I actually not because I am scared of doing it. I don't know if it will effect my current ports or not. Like I mentioned I have very version specific ports and I don't want to break my current setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message should have directed you [here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration).

You appear to have attempted to do Step 4 before Step 3.

You need to upgrade MacPorts itself to a version that supports Catalina *before* you can use it to upgrade all the software you previously installed using it.

You can download a precompiled binary for Catalina from the [install page](https://www.macports.org/install.php).

Comment: Anyone who considers reinstalling MacPorts on Catalina today, should tread carefullly. For me it opened a hornet's nest, a lot of packages do not compile without patches and fixes. Some are pretty basic (e.g. gcc9). I would think hard before reinstalling until it's released, and consider testing it on a separate path.